# PlatformIO support for TinyScreen+

Tags: arduino, platformio

I am having trouble uploading an Arduino sketch to the TinyScreen+ using PlatformIO. The upload is successful but the TinyScreen+ will not boot. If I use the Arduino IDE the upload and boot are just fine.

I looked into the output of both the Arduino IDE and PlatformIO when uploading and everything is the same except for the size of the firmware.  The PlatformIO .bin is bigger by 2 pages. Does this matter? Also why the successful upload but no boot when uploading using PlatformIO?

Here is my platformio.ini:

```
[platformio]
src_dir=src/tinywatch

[common_env_data]
lib_deps_builtin =
  TinyScreen
  Wire
lib_deps_external =
  https://github.com/cbolgiano/tinywatch/raw/develop/libs/Time-
master.zip
  https://github.com/cbolgiano/tinywatch/raw/develop/libs/arduino-BLEPeripheral-master.zip
  https://github.com/cbolgiano/tinywatch/raw/develop/libs/tinywatch-time.zip

[env:tinyscreen+]
platform = atmelsam

board = mkrzero

framework = arduino

lib_deps =
  ${common_env_data.lib_deps_builtin}
  ${common_env_data.lib_deps_external}`
```

Thank you.